# Is a Caro-Kann game still advisable after 1. e4 c6 2. g4?

Tags: caro-kann

For the record, I have already made my move. I am black and I moved 2. ... d5. But I am wondering if that was a mistake. I am a total newb and am trying to learn the Caro-Kann. As I understand it, after 1. e4 c6, black should play d5 regardless of white's response. However, I have not found any analysis on 2. g4.  Was my decision to go 2. ... d5 a mistake?  Is this still a Caro-Kann game or is it something else now?

Thanks!

Comment: d5 is fine. Attacks the centre and develops.

Comment: If this is a game in progress, I'm not sure it's ethical for us to tell you if the move you just made is good or bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The g4  line is called the Spike Variation of the Caro-Kannn(B10). Commonly played line is 2...d5 with e5 there after. White gives up development of pieces for more spatial control.

Comment: Whew! I'm not a huge player (I like the game and so many facets of it, but I never play anymore), so I'm glad that you put this in -- I was looking at the original post, checking through Wikipedia, and trying to figure out 2. g4...